# Can I connect my laptop to internet through mobile phone using USB cable?

Tags: mobile-phone, internet-connection, mobile-broadband

I want to connect my laptop to internet using my mobile phone. unfortunately the laptop I have now has no bluetooth. And mobile phone has no wifi...

Can I use the phone as modem through USB cable which came with the phone?

Comment: Yes, like Remy says. Usually all the Nokia can connect to the internet if you install Nokia PC Suite.

Comment: Thanks guys. The phone is Sony-Eric W890 and also I have Samsung Monte. The operator is Orange UK. I dont think there is limitation on use the phone as a modem. I will just leave them if so. No big deal. I am going to try tomorrow and tell how it did go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I've done it in the past.  It depends on the phone - I know that the Samsung Caliber can do it.

You probably should have a data plan already; otherwise, I imagine the cellular provider would take a very dim view of your activites...

If it does work, you might want to find the place where your phone accumulates the amount of data transfered and reset it; using this accumulator you can track how much you use (my data plan is limited to 5Gb per month).

I should add: one sure way to go over the limit is to stream constantly - whether with BitTorrent or with streaming audio/video - you'll go over a 5Gb limit in no time.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the phone yes, but be careful with your cell phone plan. Many providers detect phone-as-modem and will charge you a pretty penny if you do not have a plan that covers it. Might want to see if others online have tried it with your model and plan and see if they get charged. Play it safe and don't torrent as well, they often ding you either way for massive downloads in short periods (10gb a month or more).

Comment: I guess I should mention that if it is Windows Mobile and on the Sprint network I have a friend that cannot tether using the normal methods as he doesn't have a plan that supports it. He can however use WMWiFiRouter to connect and do USB based tethering.